# RMagick complains it was configured with a different version of ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

I am getting following error while running local `script/server` of my Rails project:

> This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.1 but ImageMagick 6.4.5 is in use. (RuntimeError)

Running `identify --version` shows the following:

> Version: ImageMagick 6.6.1-10 2010-05-21 Q8 http://www.imagemagick.org

So, my question is how and where should I make changes to work it fine; I have already reinstalled ImageMagick but that didn't work.

Comment: what do you get with ruby -e 'require "RMagick"'

Answer (score 83, accepted):

the same thing happened to me but the solution was a bit simpler than uninstalling imageMagick.  It sounds like Rmagick's config file isn't updated to use your updated imagemagick so try

```
sudo gem uninstall rmagick
sudo gem install rmagick
```

restart your server.

I took a closer look and noticed you had Rmagick configured for a newer imageMagick but using an older imageMagick.  So I would assume that my solution would still work but you would not be using the newer ImageMagick.

Comment: Installing and uninstalling rmagick gem solved the issue for me too.

Comment: If using bundler: 

`bundle exec gem uninstall rmagick`

`bundle`

Comment: Worked for me too, this was my error: `This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.8.6 but ImageMagick 6.8.7-0 is in use`

Comment: Curiously enough, `rvmsudo uninstall rmagick` and then `rvmsudo install rmagick -v 'version.I.need'` actually did it. Thanks! :O

Answer (score 38):

If using bundler:

`bundle exec gem uninstall rmagick`

`bundle install` (will reinstall rmagick as part of the bundle)

Answer (score 9):

I would remove any previous installation and start again by following [this page](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-linux.html).
First of all open a shell and launch:

```
identify -version
```

which will give you the IM version installed on your system.

Depending on how You installed IM, find the way to remove It **completely** from the system. For instance if you used apt-get, try:

```
sudo apt-get remove ImageMagick
```

If you installed IM from sources, go to where you have them stored (I mean the sources path/folder) and type:

```
make uninstall
```

You can then reinstall ImageMagick, compiling it from the sources:

```
cd
wget ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz 
tar zxf ImageMagick.tar.gz 
cd ImageMagick-*/ 
./configure --prefix=$HOME --without-perl
make
make install
```

Then you have to add $HOME/bin to the beginning of your $PATH

```
cd
echo "export PATH=$HOME/bin:\$PATH" >> .bash_profile
source .bash_profile
```

Now it's time to gem install RMagick:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for instant reply i would check that one and get back

Comment: irongaze's answer helped me when I installed in standard /usr/local prefix http://superuser.com/questions/361435/i-have-compiled-imagemagick-on-my-centos-and-rmagick-wont-install

Comment: Check Skotti's solution below. That's probably what you're looking for: reinstall rmagick gem

Comment: In my experience, I have to remove another libs in Ubuntu 14.10 related with graphicsmagick like graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat. It seems that Wand-Config and Graphics-Config produce problems too for rmagick

Answer (score 6):

```
RMAGICK_BYPASS_VERSION_TEST = true
```

Thats a global flag set before requiring rmagick.

from
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/librmagick-ruby/+bug/565461/comments/2

Worked and tested ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by uninstalling and then deleting the file listed in the error message (before reinstalling). It seems that uninstalling doesn't always clean up some of the old ".so" files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and eventually concluded that my installation of libmagick9-dev
(sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev ruby1.8-dev) was installing ImageMagick APIs for the lower version.  My solution was to uninstall the later versions and go with the Ubuntu packaged versions of ImageMagick and the other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this on a Rails app. I tried [Scott Montgomerie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887342/rmagick-complains-it-was-configured-with-a-different-version-of-imagemagick#13304306), but I couldn't get `bundle exec gem` to work (*not sure why, no time to find out*).

What worked for me was a simple `bundle update rmagick`.

Answer (score 1):

`bundle update rmagick` worked for me