# How to tell RMagick which ImageMagick too use?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RMagick complains it was configured with a different version of ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887342/rmagick-complains-it-was-configured-with-a-different-version-of-imagemagick)

When I try the following in irb or a .rb script

> require 'rmagick'

It results in the following error message:

**RuntimeError: This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.8.1 but  ImageMagick 6.7.1-1 is in use.**

Checking ImageMagick with:

> convert --version

results: in: **Version: ImageMagick 6.8.1-10 2013-01-24 Q8 http://www.imagemagick.org**

When I do

> which convert

gives: **/usr/local/bin/convert**

I had installed ImagaMagick 6.7.1-1 in the past with Macports, but I uninstalled that already. How and where does Rmagick looks when it wants the ImageMagick libraries? I got the correct ImageMagick installed, Rmagick just needs the correct reference to it.

I'm on OS X 10.8.2 and using RVM