# This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.9 but ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 is in use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

In a rails application, I have this error message :

```
This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.9 but ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 is in use.
```

I tried to uninstall and install `RMagick` as suggested in this post : [RMagick complains it was configured with a different version of ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887342/rmagick-complains-it-was-configured-with-a-different-version-of-imagemagick), but it does not work.

I also tried to download the latest version and compile from source but it does not works.

I don't know how to install ImageMagick `6.7.7-10`. It seems to not be available on the official website.

I am using `rmagick (2.13.2)` and Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Looks like Rmagick was installed with Imagemagick 6.6.9, but you have a more current version of Imagemagick at 6.7.7.10 on your system that probably came with an upgrade of your distro. This is causing a conflict. I think you need to remove at least RMagick if not both and then re-install. I do not know RMagick, so do the know if it self-installs Imagemagick.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Instead of doing `gem uninstall rmagick` try using `bundle exec gem uninstall rmagick`.

I hope it will help someone else!

Comment: It would have been simpler to type `bundle exec update rmagick`

Answer (score 12):

For me, I did the following and it worked :

```
 gem uninstall rmagick
 bundle
```

Comment: I spent an hour tried to check different variants, but your answer was right. I don't know why it's not worked with "bundle install", but work's fine with "bundle" command.

Answer (score -1):

bundle exec uninstall rmagick, to uninstall RMagick.

Comment: While this answer may be (technically) correct, it would be helpful to future readers of this post to have some more explanation and context provided by you.